# C preprocessor macro for catching null dereferences

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

I am currently working in an embedded environment with absolutely nothing (there's a boot loader and that's it). In this case, dereferencing NULL just crashes the entire box and does not provide any information with regards to where it occurred. There are no debugging utilities.

What I do have written so far is a basic kernel, context switching as well as both interrupt-drive and busy-wait IO to a UART that allows me to print information to a terminal with our version of printf. With this, we have a function that switches into the kernel and prints something like the following through the terminal:

```
Panic("\033[31mPanic: at line %d of file %s (function <%s>): \033[0m\r\n\r\n", \__LINE__, \__FILE__, \__FUNCTION__.);
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to wrap a null check with this invocation as a macro. Something like:

```
#define SAFE_DEREF(x) (x != NULL ? *x : Panic(...))
```

but that doesn't work as a lvalue.

Obviously, I can do a manual NULL check + panic for each variable but that is a large refactor and it would increase the amount of code by a good amount.

Is this even possible to do?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the final code:

```
#define d(x) ( *(((x) ? 0 : (Panic(ASSERT_MSG, __LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, "NULL DEREF"),0)), x) )
```

Comment: Is C++ allowed? With operator overloading this looks doable.

Comment: Nope, just plain old C.

Comment: Are you sure it "just crashes" or is it possibly that the C run-time hooks to a handler that you have not implemented?  In such a case an empty loop (possibly with interrupts off) is the likely default handler. Either way I'd consider fixing this at the systems level rather than the code level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
#define SAFE_DEREF(x) ((x) ? *(x) : (Panic(),*(x)))
```

but actually that's not great because you couldn't use it as an l-value.  So, try this instead:

```
#define SAFE_DEREF(x) (*((x) ? (x) : (Panic(),(x)))
```

This still has the usual problem with macros that if (x) is an expression with side-effects, you end up performing the side-effects twice, so you have to be very careful.

```
q = SAFE_DEREF(p++); // OOPS!
```

Comment: Or `SAFE_DEREF(x) *(((x)? 0 : Panic(),0), x)` to reduce the number of expansions of x and possibly less generated code.

Comment: Or `* ( (x) || Panic(…), (x) )` would be much simpler. Double expansion sucks though.

Comment: GCC has an extension where you can omit one operand (not the first!) of the ternary operator and it evaluates to the first operand if that path is chosen; if your compiler has this extension then it avoids the double-expansion problem. `#define CHECK(p) ( (p) ?: Panic(.....) )` , where `Panic` has return type `void *` but should never actually return.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports `typeof` (or an equivalent) which does not evaluate its operand, then you can avoid the pain of macros which evaluate the operand twice:

```
inline void *pointer_check(void *x)
{
    if ( !x )
        Panic();  // don't return
    return x;
}

#define CHECK(p) ( (typeof(p)) chk(p) )
```

Now you can replace any use of `p` which performs lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (i.e. most uses except for `p = ...` which doesn't need it anyway) with `CHECK(p)` .

For example, `CHECK( func_which_returns_pointer_to_struct() ) ->member = 5;`

If you like you could include the dereference in the macro:

```
#define CHECK_DR(p) ( *CHECK(p) )
```

and this gives an lvalue.

NB. Include any arguments to 'Panic' via extra parameters to the inline function